# xlsx file to list for dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is a copy of my code when I run it the list output is in a weird format that I cant figure out how to change.

'''

```
import pandas as pd

inputdata = []
data = pd.read_excel('testfile.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['black_toner_percentage'])
for i in df.values:
    inputdata.append(i)
print(inputdata)
```

'''

array([100], dtype=int64), array([100], dtype=int64)

This is the format my list is going into and Id like it to be [100,100,ext.]
What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: your `inputdata = []` is an empty list, later, via loop you append data (row by row) to list.
if you ant to have big list for all values in the col, no loop is needed, simply use `inputdata = df["black_toner_percentage"].tolist()`